# Mouse click on dom perfomance issues geckofx(embedded win xp sp3)

Tags: c#, winforms, dom, windows-xp, geckofx

I need help to point out the bottleneck of my app.
I am using [geckofx  browser control](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx) in winforms app, running on winxp sp3. Click event propagate to dom so slow -  it might take up to couple seconds.
Some log records with nlog

```
…
2015-03-30 19:05:26.3085 TRACE WM_LBUTTONDOWN
2015-03-30 19:05:27.0585 TRACE DomClick -Gecko.DOM.GeckoButtonElement
…
```

There is no such problem in win7 - it running  fast on it.
Here code of my mainform
**MainForm.cs**

```
 ….
        public MainForm()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            //catching win messages
            Application.AddMessageFilter(this);

           Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User["layers.accelerate-all"] = true;

            this.Load += MainForm_Load;


        }

        void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LogAllEvents();

        }
…

        private void LogAllEvents()
        {
            geckoWebBrowser.WindowSetBounds += (s, e) => { _logger.Trace("WindowSetBounds - " + e.Bounds); };
            geckoWebBrowser.Paint += (s, e) => { _logger.Trace("Paint -" + e.ClipRectangle); };
            geckoWebBrowser.Invalidated += (s, e) => { _logger.Trace("Invalidated -" + e.InvalidRect); };
            geckoWebBrowser.DomClick += (s, e) => { _logger.Trace("DomClick -" + e.Target.ToString()); };
            geckoWebBrowser.DocumentCompleted += (s, e) => { _logger.Trace("DocumentCompleted -" ); };
        }



public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
        {

                if (m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
                {
                    _logger.Trace("WM_LBUTTONDOWN");
                    return false;
                }
                else
                    if (m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONUP)
                    {
                        _logger.Trace("WM_LBUTTONUP");
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                        return false;

        }
```

**MainForm.Designer.cs**

```
 …            
    // BrowserHolder
                // 
                this.BrowserHolder.Controls.Add(this.geckoWebBrowser);
                this.BrowserHolder.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
                this.BrowserHolder.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 28);
                this.BrowserHolder.Name = "BrowserHolder";
                this.BrowserHolder.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1180, 554);
                this.BrowserHolder.TabIndex = 2;
                // 
                // geckoWebBrowser
                // 
                this.geckoWebBrowser.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
                this.geckoWebBrowser.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
                this.geckoWebBrowser.Name = "geckoWebBrowser";
                this.geckoWebBrowser.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1180, 554);
                this.geckoWebBrowser.TabIndex = 0;
                this.geckoWebBrowser.UseHttpActivityObserver = false;
     …
```

BrowserHolder is panel that wrap webbrowser control.

I don’t have any clue what’s going on, cpu usage under 10 percent.
**Here’s my machine**: ms windows embedded POSready 2009 ver2.0 service pack3
Intel Atom D2500 ,1.86 ghz ,1.98 gb of ram
**Geckofx 16 and 31** –same result – very slow click

---

### UPDATE

We recently decide to use [cefsharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) ver-33, and it working lovely on target machine with no delay, but i still looking for answer for geckofx

Comment: Hey - sorry, but what exactly are you doing? - .DomClick event occurs when a dom element is clicked - either normally by mouse or by .Click() method. Are you trying to propagate an element?
Perhaps the difference between XP and Win7 that you get is all in the machine capabilities and how fast is Visual Studio on it?

Comment: @Bartosz thanx for reply, i tried to make simple browser and clicking on buttons by mouse on html page workin slow, unfortunately i can not set up vs on it, at the same time firefox with same version work properly on that machine

Comment: Sorry, so you're saying that there is a delay between the time you click on a DOM element and when the event is triggered? and you're not using visual studio?

Comment: i am using vs on my deleloper macine with win7 x86, and it's work fine, but on target machine which described above i have this delay between click and triggering of event